# @HTML Dropdownlist selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm new to Razor and I don't get why my selected value is not working.

`var listItems = (List<Categories>)ViewBag.Categories;`

Used in

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.TagActivities.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.TagActivities[i].TAGActivityId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.TagActivities[i].CategoryId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"
         <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.TagActivities[i].ActivityName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.TagActivities[i].ActivityDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model.TagActivities[i].Category.CategoryName, new SelectList(listItems, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", Model.TagActivities[i].Category.CategoryName), new { @class = "form-control" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.TagActivities[i].AlertMinutes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.TagActivities[i].IsDefault)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Help please. Thank you.

Comment: What does `listItems` look like?

Comment: @James just a list containing two columns ("CategoryId", "CategoryName")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because the selected value you pass is not of the same type at the objects in `listItems`. Once possible solution it would be to change the value you pass to the constructor of `SelectList` for the selected object:

```
new SelectList(listItems, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", Model.TagActivities[i].Category)
```

The `listItems` is a list of objects of type `Categories`. So as a selected object you should pass an object of this type.